# Why the accuracy is high on both training and validation set but very low on test set?

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm using Tensorflow to train a classifier for image recognition, the model below is built via Keras.

The original data is (50000, 3072), and reduced to (50000, 100) with PCA.
The explained ratio is 91%, which is still pretty good.
`y` is a 1-dimension array represents for 100 labels(from 0 to 99).

After that, I used the `sklearn.train_test_split` to split training and test data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_r, y, random_state=42)
```

Model and training.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(N_FEATURES,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Convert to tpu model.
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
history = tpu_model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        batch_size=128 * 8,
                        validation_split=0.2)
tpu_model.save_weights('./tpu_model.h5', overwrite=True)

tpu_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128 * 8)
```

And the output is.

```
Epoch 1/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 11s 304us/sample - loss: 4.8867 - acc: 0.0640 - val_loss: 4.5686 - val_acc: 0.1130
Epoch 2/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 4.4489 - acc: 0.1266 - val_loss: 4.2952 - val_acc: 0.1466
Epoch 3/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 24us/sample - loss: 4.2328 - acc: 0.1645 - val_loss: 4.1275 - val_acc: 0.1840
Epoch 4/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 24us/sample - loss: 4.0928 - acc: 0.1878 - val_loss: 4.0073 - val_acc: 0.2098
Epoch 5/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 3.9866 - acc: 0.2078 - val_loss: 3.9118 - val_acc: 0.2193
Epoch 6/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 24us/sample - loss: 3.8946 - acc: 0.2247 - val_loss: 3.8255 - val_acc: 0.2388
Epoch 7/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 3.8157 - acc: 0.2398 - val_loss: 3.7456 - val_acc: 0.2488
Epoch 8/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 3.7425 - acc: 0.2549 - val_loss: 3.6762 - val_acc: 0.2699
Epoch 9/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 24us/sample - loss: 3.6728 - acc: 0.2675 - val_loss: 3.6140 - val_acc: 0.2780
Epoch 10/125
...
Epoch 116/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 0.5966 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5922 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 117/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 0.5963 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5913 - val_acc: 0.9997
Epoch 118/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5949 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5905 - val_acc: 0.9997
Epoch 119/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5939 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5895 - val_acc: 0.9997
Epoch 120/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5932 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5892 - val_acc: 0.9999
Epoch 121/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5932 - acc: 0.9997 - val_loss: 0.5884 - val_acc: 0.9997
Epoch 122/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5920 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5877 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 123/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 26us/sample - loss: 0.5927 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5871 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 124/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 25us/sample - loss: 0.5909 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5864 - val_acc: 0.9999
Epoch 125/125
37500/37500 [==============================] - 1s 24us/sample - loss: 0.5899 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.5855 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

It looks good and it doesn't feel like there is an overfitting problem since the accuracy is extremely high on both training and validation set.
But when it comes to the test data, the accuracy is 0.19, which is unacceptably low.

```
12500/12500 [==============================] - 2s 131us/sample - loss: 5.6223 - acc: 0.1931
[5.622251008605957, 0.1931018]
```

I've tried to use the different regularisation terms, but the test accuracy is still around 20-25%.

It really confused me a lot.
Any opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: It may be a case of overfitting. The validation data is a split of 0.2 from the train data. Maybe the model has overfitted on that training data and therefore there are inefficient results of the test data which is completely new for the model.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal But the training data has 37500 samples. In addition, I checked the label distribution, it is almost average on 100 classes.